# reactjs pass multiple elements

Tags: javascript, svg, reactjs

I'm playing with reactjs and svg. I'm trying to pass multiple element states from App to Circle. Is there a way of passing it in one go, as opposed to

```
<Circle h={this.state.h} w={this.state.w} and so on />
```

See the code below:

```
class Circle extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <svg height="100" width="100">
        <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" 
          stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" 
        />
      </svg> 
    )
  }
}

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      h: 100,
      w: 100,
      cx: 50,
      cy: 50,
      r: 40,
      stroke: "black",
      fill: "red"
    }
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
      <Circle />
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'))
```

Comment: `<Circle { ...this.state } />`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Use ES6 spread operator:](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator)

```
render() {
    return (
      <div>
      <Circle {...this.state} />
      </div>
    )
}
```

And then in Circle:

```
class Circle extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { h, x, y, w, r, stroke, fill } = this.props;
    return (
      <svg height={h} width={w}>
        <circle cx={x} cy={y} r={r} 
          stroke={stroke} stroke-width="3" fill={fill} 
        />
      </svg> 
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Of course

```
const props = {
  w: this.state.w,
  h: this.state.h,
  ...
}

<Circle {...props} />

// or pass content of `state`
<Circle {...this.state} />
```

Answer (score 1):

You can! Using the [ES2015](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) spread operator on the object. (More about that in JSX [here](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-spread.html))

Your code using that would look like:

```
class Circle extends React.Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props)
    console.log(this.props)
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <svg height="100" width="100">
        <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" 
          stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" 
        />
      </svg> 
    )
  }
}

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {
      h: 100,
      w: 100,
      cx: 50,
      cy: 50,
      r: 40,
      stroke: "black",
      fill: "red"
    }
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
      <Circle {...this.state}/>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'))
```